# For $a>0,$find the minimum value of the integral $\int_0^{1/a}(a^3+4x-a^5x^2)e^{ax}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration

For $a>0,$find the minimum value of the integral $\int_0^{1/a}(a^3+4x-a^5x^2)e^{ax}dx.$

---

Let $f(a)=\int_0^{1/a}(a^3+4x-a^5x^2)e^{ax}dx$
$f'(a)=(a^3+\frac{4}{a}-a^3)e=\frac{4e}{a}$
I am stuck here.

Comment: Use Leibniz rule.

Comment: You have to do the integral in terms of $x$.  Can you integrate $x^2e^{ax}$?  Do it by parts with $ u=x^2$  Once you evaluate it you can take the derivative with respect to $a$

Comment: Calculate the integral.

Comment: The endpoints of the integration range depend on $a$, too. Be careful in applying the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Why does this happen that when the end points of the integration range depend on $a$,we cannot differentiate with respect to $a$@JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The endpoints of the integration range depend on $a$, too, so you have to be careful in applying the fundamental theorem of Calculus. We have

$$ I(a) = \int_{0}^{1/a}(a^3+4x-a^5 x^2)e^{ax}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto z/a}{=} \int_{0}^{1}\left(a^2+\frac{4z}{a^2}-a^2 z^2\right)e^z\,dz \tag{1}$$
hence
$$ I(a) = \frac{4+a^4}{a^2} \stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}{\geq} \frac{4a^2}{a^2} = \color{red}{4}\tag{2} $$
with equality attained at $a=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $4+a^4\geq 2\sqrt{4a^4}=4a^2$, so the minimum is $4$. (+1)

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima here is the equality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: Why your $I (a) $ does not contain $e $.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: I guess because the primitive is related to $(x-1)e^x$ whose value at $1$ does not really depend on $e$.

Comment: @Math-fun: correct. Thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**
Brute force is to note that 
$$
f(a) = a^3 \int_0^{1/a} e^{ax}dx + 4\int_0^{1/a} xe^{ax}dx
     - a^5\int_0^{1/a} x^2e^{ax}dx
$$
the first integral is straight-forward, the second can be taken by parts, and the third requires by parts twice.

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

Put $t=ax $.

the integral becomes

$$\int_0^1 (a^2+\frac {4}{a^2}t-a^2t^2)e^tdt$$

the minimum of the integrand is attained for $t=2a^{-4}$ since its derivative is

$$\frac {4}{a^2}-2a^2t$$

Comment: $t$ is the integration parameter, the minimum has to be attained at some value of $a$, not $t$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio i think one must find t and then a.

Comment: Not at all. $$\text{argmin}\int_{0}^{1}f_a(t)\,dt $$ is a value for $a$.